# How to write a c++ operator overload for input/output without knowing the type when using it

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

I made an operator:

```
template <typename Container>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Container& container) {
string result = "{";

out << result;

return out;
}
```

When I want to use it:

```
enum class space { empty, full, half };
using elements_t = vector<space>;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    elements_t elems = { space::half };
    cout << elems;
    return 0;
}
```

It throws an error :

'operator <<' is ambiguous.

How do you specify that you want to use the custom one? I know that with a template function you'd assign the types afterwards in <> and if I had a specific class/struct I could make the operator be local or friend, but what if I want it to be global?

Comment: C++ does not work this way. It is the template declaration that specifies what kind of parameters it is defined for, and if it matches a reference it gets used. You don't get to simply define a template for some unspecified type, and then specify it, explicitly, every time you use it. That's not how templates are used in C++. Well, you could, by explicitly invoking it, but even that doesn't always work correctly in some cases, like with templates with multiple variadic parameter packs, as parameters.

Comment: Btw, the question how you actually output types which don't have a std::operator<<() is kind of open ;-). It may be better to go the normal way and provide a non-template operator for each specific type you have (like your vector of enums). Then you know inside the operator which type you actually have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I try your program, the compiler complains about the `operator<<()` *inside* your custom operator definition (better to copy the exact error message including the line number). I suppose you want to use `std::operator<<` here (recurring would result in an infinite recursion). To do that, you exactly write that:

```
template <typename Container>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Container& container) {
    std::string result = "{";

    std::operator<<(out, result);
    return out;
}
```

Comment: thanks I was being dumb, basically the << in my custom declared one had to be specified to be from std. I thought it was complaining about the one in main, my eyes missed the line in the error.

Comment: Also, please add type traits, at least, otherwise this breaks `operator<<` for almost everything else. Better yet: give it a unique name, rather than `operator<<`.

Comment: @MooingDuck "give it a unique name", probably by putting it in its own namespace.

Comment: namespace definately but @MooingDuck how do I add type traits? For example, I want my Container to be array

Comment: Matching only an array would be easy: `template <typename Element, int len>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Element (&container)[len])`. If you wanted to match any sort of container, you'd need to look up SFINAE, as it gets really tricky.

Comment: @MooingDuck No meta programming expert here, but couldn't you for a solution which fits any container (but only containers) simply use iterators? `begin( )` and `end()` would compile with any container (including arrays) but lead to compile time errors for other types. -- Oh. Would that break `cout << 1`  etc. because the template is found first but does not compile? Hm.

Comment: You can use `template<class Container,
    class iit = decltype(std::begin(std::declval<Container>()))>
 std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Container& container) {
     typename std::ostream_iterator<decltype(*std::begin(container))> oit;
     std::copy(std::begin(container), std::end(container), oit(out));
     return out;
 }`, but since it works for any container, now there's two `operator<<` for `std::string`, so it breaks the ability to `<<` a `std::string`, which is sort of important.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fcbd89a5f40a488e

Comment: Yeah, that's bad. Is it because the `operator<<`  for strings is also a template?